How to disable Windows S mode - while I think this laptop is not in S mode
This Lenovo laptop has Windows 11 Pro with all the latest updates. We use a VLSC license to install Office 2019 and this works for most of our laptops. Except this one. It says that I need to get out of Windows S mode to be able to install Office 2019. I search for solutions, and I find a Wikihow guide to handle this.
Settings > System > Activation

When I open the Activation settings, it should show that the laptop is in S mode, but it doesn't. The result is that there is no button to deactivate it.

Disable Secure Boot

I disabled Secure Boot
Restarting then should fix the problem and disable S mode, except it doesn't.

S mode - MS Store only

I've downloaded Firefox from the Mozilla website, then installed it
Doesn't S mode prevent the installation of apps outside the MS Store?

Questions

Does this prove that this laptop is not in S mode?
What can I do to get out of S mode?


Solution
At first I found a detour. I installed Windows 10, then installed Office 2019 VLSC, then upgraded to Windows 11. But this is not the solution you want. Emily reminded me that I maybe used an old deployment tool, and that was indeed the case. After updating, I could install Office.

This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Windows 11 in S mode is only available in the Windows 11 Home edition..  This question needs a lot of work before I feel comfortable answering the question.  If you are asking how to disable S Mode on your device, then you need to confirm it's actually enabled, before asking the question.  If you don't know how to confirm that is the case, then I would expect a clear question, asking how to do that.

How did you install the Office 2019?
I suggest you download the latest version of ODT:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49117
Then try the configuration file (It is for Office Professional Plus 2019):
<Configuration>
<OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="PerpetualVL2019">
<Product ID="ProPlus2019Volume">
<Language ID="en-us" />
</Add>
<RemoveMSI />
<Display Level="None" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
</Configuration>

If you need to install Office Standard 2019, the Product ID is Standard2019Volume.
The reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/deploy

The laptop is from what I hear not in S mode.
Perhaps Microsoft Office believes it's in S mode due to some registry entry, which is weird, since how can anyone run the Office installer on a computer while it's in S mode?
I can't make up a direct solution since I have no idea why it's giving such error, so I will first give some tips to find out what's happening.
To troubleshoot further I suggest launching procmon, enabling capture as the installation starts and stopping capture as soon as the error shows up. Then you can try to figure out what the last file or registry key it accessed before throwing the error. You can also export the captured events in procmon and send them here so I can try to see if I find something out of the ordinary.
Another place to look is the event viewer, there are likely logs there. The logs probably have more explanation on what's really going on.
I am pretty certain this problem is caused by a registry entry but I wouldn't know which one or how it ended up getting altered in a way that causes problems.
If you don't have the patience to figure it out, an in-place upgrade might help, and if that doesn't work you can reinstall the operating system without reformatting and have it move the old files to Windows.old so you can restore the files, but settings will be gone if you do this. I don't recommend reinstalling Windows if it's something that can be fixed, so first you can try troubleshooting.

I bet there is a way to fix this in the registry, but that's way to complicated. I used an old deployment tool, and after updating it all worked.
